# LQP Review strange Answer to strange question by suspicious user

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I've just come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644297/what-are-the-minimum-operational-performance-standards-for-rtos-in-aviations) in the [Low Quality Post Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10845087). Specifically about [the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644297/what-are-the-minimum-operational-performance-standards-for-rtos-in-aviations/34712764#34712764) to that question. Now this is absolutely not my subject Area, absolutely nothing I know anything about. But it sounds like a Question closeable as Hardware/Software recommendation. The user posting the Question posted it shortly after he signed up, then nothing else from then on.

The answerer signed on 2 days ago, and this answer is his first Answer.

To my untrained eyes this looks deeply suspicious, I would appreciate 
if anyone who can understand this better can deal with this or tell me how I should have dealt with this.

I ended up skipping the review for this.

Comment: I see it has been deleted now. Can anyone comment on what exactly that was? Just a bad question with a bad answer, or something more nefarious?.

Comment: Don't know. I don't think moderators have had a chance to look at it yet. I haven't. It was deleted by meta effect.

Comment: To me it looks like your typical everyday Off Topic question (also typically, very badly asked) but with a random spam-like answer – unrelated to the asker.

Comment: @BoltClock I didn't flag it for moderator attention before and now I can't view it. Is there another way besides asking in meta to make a moderator look at this?

Comment: Nothing suspicious about it.  This is a question on the far end of the very long tail of SO, somebody wants to know how to get his real-time kernel certified to be usable on aircraft.  Answered by an engineer who works for the Spanish equivalent of the FAA and is familiar with the procedures.  Answer is correct, you can't get just the kernel certified.  English is not his first language, that's pretty obvious, could have been banged into shape with an edit if anybody cared enough.  Nobody does, it is pretty lonely on the far end of the tail.

Comment: Yep, seems legit, just awful.

Comment: @Hans: That comment should be an answer to this meta post.  Unfortunately I don't think there's any way to generalize from this case, other than "read the answerer's profile" for clues about his perspective.

Comment: @Jongware: What about that answer strikes you as spam-like?  To me it seems a bit rambling (both being a new user and English-as-a-second-language likely contribute to that) but there's not even a hint of connection to any commercial tools or services that I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only advice I can give you is to check the post scores: had either the crappy question or the crappy answer been upvoted, I may have suspected a vote fraud ring being formed. Not a particularly effective one, mind you.

In this case, neither post had anything but downvotes so I think we can safely conclude that this was simple misadventure by two unfortunate post authors.